# Angular 7 ngOnDestroy unsubscribe not removing subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

So on one of my pages I am subscribing to the back button press in order to prompt the user with something. I then unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` in order to remove this as I don't want it on any other pages. However when I navigate to another page it doesn't remove the subscription so when I hit back on the next page it goes back then triggers the subscription contents.

How can I stop this from happening.

Start sub:

```
backBtnSub;

ngOnInit() {    
    this.backBtnSub = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
        this.showAlert();
    });
}
```

Remove sub:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.backBtnSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Where I navigate away:

```
<div class="option" routerLink="/main/documents">
    <img class="optionImg" src="../../../assets/images/docs.png" alt="Option Image">
    <p class="optionText">Docs</p>
</div>
```

Does `routerLink` not trigger ngOnDestroy? My only solution I can think of would be to create my own "navigate" function where I unsubscribe then navigate away but I don't think that should be required.

Comment: Did you checked putting console.log() on ngOnDestroy, is it being called on changing routes?

Comment: is `OnDestroy()` even called? I suspect your page is not destroyed, if you don't pop it. try `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`

Comment: Maybe a CanDeactivate guard could be the better solution here?

Comment: ngOnDestroy () will be invoked only if the component is destroyed

Comment: I wanted to use ionView things, but where do you import them from, and console log doesn't give anything it's not being called on navigate

Comment: you don't need to import them, just use them.

Comment: Okay! yep that works, but when I go back how can I get the page to refresh so that it's re-subscribed again? "ionDidReturn" something like that

Comment: Please refer to the documentation. you can use `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewWillEnter`. docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: ... and remove code from `OnInit` of course.